# Using smarty template engine to translate the array of key value given below to the language chosen?

Tags: smarty

I am trying to  use  foreach loop in smarty template engine  so that I can  translate  the array of key value  given below to the language chosen.  ok but i am solved this problem in core php. But I am facing problem in smarty template engine.

**Example In php**

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $trans[$row['form_field_labels_key']] = $row['form_field_labels_name'];
}
```

My key value are in `key = form_field_labels_name` and `value =form_field_labels_name`.

Given array:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 3
                [form_field_labels_key] => Personal_Information
                [form_field_labels_name] => தனிப்பட்ட தகவல்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:21:27
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 6
                [form_field_labels_key] => NRIC
                [form_field_labels_name] => NRIC / இறகு / இல்லை அடையாள எண்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:23:13
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 9
                [form_field_labels_key] => Title
                [form_field_labels_name] => தலைப்பு
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:26:55
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 11
                [form_field_labels_key] => Name
                [form_field_labels_name] => பெயர்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:28:41
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 15
                [form_field_labels_key] => Apartment_no
                [form_field_labels_name] => அபார்ட்மெண்ட்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:30:34
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 18
                [form_field_labels_key] => Apartment_name
                [form_field_labels_name] => அடுக்குமாடி / கட்டிடம் பெயர்.
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:32:52
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 21
                [form_field_labels_key] => Street_Name
                [form_field_labels_name] => தெரு பெயர்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:35:40
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 24
                [form_field_labels_key] => Unit_No
                [form_field_labels_name] => அலகு இல்லை
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:37:25
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 27
                [form_field_labels_key] => Province
                [form_field_labels_name] => மாகாணம்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:39:38
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 30
                [form_field_labels_key] => City_State
                [form_field_labels_name] => நகரம் / மாநிலம்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:42:03
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 33
                [form_field_labels_key] => Zip_Postal
                [form_field_labels_name] => ஜிப் / அஞ்சல் குறியீடு
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:43:40
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 36
                [form_field_labels_key] => Country
                [form_field_labels_name] => நாடு
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:47:27
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 39
                [form_field_labels_key] => Home_Tel
                [form_field_labels_name] => வீட்டில் தொலைபேசி
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:48:42
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 42
                [form_field_labels_key] => Office_Tel
                [form_field_labels_name] => அலுவலக தொலைபேசி
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:50:25
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 45
                [form_field_labels_key] => Mobile
                [form_field_labels_name] => மொபைல்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:55:40
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 48
                [form_field_labels_key] => Email
                [form_field_labels_name] => மின்னஞ்சல்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:55:50
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [16] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 51
                [form_field_labels_key] => Please_provide_email_for_successful
                [form_field_labels_name] => வெற்றிகரமான ஆன்லைன் உத்தரவாதத்தை பதிவு அறிவிப்பு மின்னஞ்சல் வழங்கவும்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 15:58:45
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [17] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 54
                [form_field_labels_key] => Purchase_Information
                [form_field_labels_name] => தகவல் வாங்க
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 16:08:04
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [18] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 57
                [form_field_labels_key] => Receipt_No
                [form_field_labels_name] => ரசீது இல்லை
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 16:09:16
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 60
                [form_field_labels_key] => Date_of_Purchase
                [form_field_labels_name] => கொள்முதல் தேதி
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 16:11:51
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [20] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 63
                [form_field_labels_key] => Place_of_Purchase
                [form_field_labels_name] => கொள்முதல் இடத்தில்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 16:13:19
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [21] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 66
                [form_field_labels_key] => Country_of_Purchase
                [form_field_labels_name] => கொள்முதல் நாட்டின்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 16:15:00
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [22] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 69
                [form_field_labels_key] => Country_of_Registration
                [form_field_labels_name] => பதிவு நாடு
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 16:18:37
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [23] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 72
                [form_field_labels_key] => Product_Information
                [form_field_labels_name] => தயாரிப்பு தகவல்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 16:22:10
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [24] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 75
                [form_field_labels_key] => Model_No
                [form_field_labels_name] => மாதிரி இல்லை
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 16:31:36
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [25] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 78
                [form_field_labels_key] => Serial_No
                [form_field_labels_name] => இல்லை தொடர்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 16:33:05
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [26] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 81
                [form_field_labels_key] => Warranty_Card_No
                [form_field_labels_name] => உத்தரவாதத்தை அட்டை இல்லை
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 16:38:00
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

        [27] => Array
            (
                [form_field_labels_id] => 84
                [form_field_labels_key] => Please_fill_in_all_mandatory
                [form_field_labels_name] => '*' ஆல் குறிப்பிடப்பட்டு அனைத்து கட்டாய நிரப்புக. நீங்கள் தயாராக இருக்கும் போது, வெறும் 'பதிவு' கிளிக்
                [language_id] => 3
                [published] => 1
                [created_date] => 2013-09-13 16:41:28
                [last_modified_date] => 
            )

    )
```

Comment: Whats the issue? Which output are you expecting? And which output are you getting instead?

Answer (score 0):

smarty code

```
{* create empty arrays for array_push function *}
{assign var="keys" value=','|explode:""}
{assign var="values" value=','|explode:""}


{* cready arrays with keys and values *}
{foreach from=$given_array item=value}

{assign var=$keys value=$keys|@array_push:$value.form_field_labels_key}
{assign var=$values value=$values|@array_push:$value.form_field_labels_name}

{/foreach}

{* remove first empty elemet *}
{assign var=$keys value=$keys|@array_shift}
{assign var=$values value=$values|@array_shift}

{* combine array *}
{assign var="result" value=$keys|@array_combine:$values}

{* test output *}
{foreach from=$result item="value" key="key"}

    {$key} | {$value}<br>

{/foreach}
```

here is what we have in $result

```
Personal_Information | தனிப்பட்ட தகவல்
NRIC | NRIC / இறகு / இல்லை அடையாள எண்
Title | தலைப்பு
```